# Where can I find stalkers after the main quest?

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm completing the shaman's quest where I have to kill and get a stalker's bone, but I already cleared the cauldron area, where can I find another stalker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stalkers can be found in The Fjord.

Comment: They pine for it.